# Oracle SQL query regarding group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

i have 2 tables, article and caretaker with following columns and structure

```
SQL> desc caretaker;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CID                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 CNAME                                              VARCHAR2(15)
 ADDRESS                                            VARCHAR2(20)
 SALARY                                             NUMBER(10,2)

SQL> desc article;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ART_NO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(5)
 ART_TITLE                                          VARCHAR2(15)
 TYPE                                               VARCHAR2(15)
 A_DATE                                             DATE
 CID                                                NUMBER(5)
 MUSEUM_ID                                          NUMBER(5)
```

and i need to execute 2 queries,

1) find the details of the articles cared by person whose salary is more than 20000 and who takes care of atleast 2 articles

2)display the details of the caretaker taking care of maximum articles.

for the 1st query i have made it do far

```
select a.art_no,a.art_title,a.type,a.a_date from article a,caretaker c 
where a.cid = c.cid and c.salary > 20000;
```

now i am confused about on how to extract the articles which are cared by person who takes care of atleast 2 articles?!!

2)for the second query,

```
select c.cid,c.cname,c.address,c.salary from caretaker c,article a 
where c.cid=a.cid 
    and count( select a.cid from article a group by a.cid ) = MAX(a.cid)?????
```

am confused,please correct me,thank you
(I'm not supposed to JOIN commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first query:

```
select a.art_no,a.art_title,a.type,a.a_date 
from article a,caretaker c
where a.cid = c.cid and c.salary > 20000
and c.cid in (select cid from article group by cid having count(cid) > 1)
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bef24/16

For the second query:

```
select cname, a.art_no,a.art_title,a.type,a.a_date 
from article a,caretaker c
where a.cid = c.cid and c.cid = (select cid 
                                 from(select cid, count(cid)
                                      from article
                                      group by cid
                                      having count(cid) = (select max(count(cid)) 
                                                     from article group by cid)));
```

**SQL Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bef24/18

Comment: select a.art_no,a.art_title,a.type,a.a_date 
from article a ,caretaker c 
where a.cid=c.cid and c.salary > 20000
and c.cid in (select cid from article group by cid having count(cid) > 1)

would this work?

Comment: You were already using a join in the original. Just not the explicit syntax.

Comment: Thank you,i replaced the join and got the 1st query working :)

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: yes,i guess so, for the second query,i would have to display the caretaker information(you query displays the article information),so i modified your query and got the care taker information who is taking care of maximum number of article

here it is
select distinct * from(
select c.cid,c.cname,c.address,c.salary from caretaker c,article a
where c.cid=a.cid and
a.cid=(select cid from(select cid,count(cid) from article group by cid having count(cid)=(select max(count(cid)) from article group by cid) ))
);

Comment: @AbhiJith Glad to hear its working! If this solved your question please consider accepting the answer.